# Very strange balance in poloneix

Tags: exchanges

I believe I transfer 1.3 bitcoin from exchange account to lending account.

Then I saw I have only .29 bitcoin left in my lending account.

So I did a search.

This is what I found

[image]

It says I have .29 balance in lending. I have 1.3 bitcoins.

I check my balance and it does say that I have 1.3 bitcoins.

However, 1 BTC is in "orders"

[image]

What orders? Open orders? None. None of my BTC are in open orders.

[image]
My zec balance is only small. So I do not think it's the issue.
[image]

Comment: I think its your best bet, to contact poloniex support for this.

Comment: I already did. Maybe the guy I lend btc too put it on orders. I have no idea why. Shouldn't it still be listed as my lending?